MS Project Export as CSV not generating non english language data
I have been following below link to save MS Project file as CSV
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-or-import-data-to-another-file-format-6e6e581f-a580-4f04-aa87-9b6552143d9c#:~:text=Choose%20File%20%3E%20Save%20As.%20Choose%20Browse.%20In,a%20name%20for%20the%20exported%20file.%20Choose%20Save
using Existing Task Export Map to save as CSV
Issue i am facing is after generating CSV, non English data is getting corrupted, showing as "????????" in the CSV

CSV File generated is getting saved as ANSI encoding, there is no way to change it to UTF 8 in Export Wizard
these are all steps can be done Mannully on MS Project
I also have MSPPlugin written in DotNet which does same exact steps programmatically
have used below APIs to perform the same
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.mapedit
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.filesaveas
Dim g_projAppObj As MSProject.Application

g_projAppObj.MapEdit(Name:="Task Export Map", Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True,
    DataCategory:=MSProject.PjDataCategories.pjMapTasks,
    FieldName:="Task_UID", ExternalFieldName:="Task_UID",
    CategoryEnabled:=True, TableName:="Task Export Map", ImportMethod:=0, HeaderRow:=True,
    AssignmentData:=False, TextDelimiter:=",",
    TextFileOrigin:=MSProject.PjTextFileOrigin.pjTextOriginUnicode,
    UseHtmlTemplate:=False, IncludeImage:=False)

g_projAppObj.FileSaveAs(Name:=w_FileName, Format:=MSProject.PjFileFormat.pjCSV, Map:="Task Export Map")

getting same output as shown in screenshot
Note: I have MS Project 2019 Standard

I don't know if this is an option for you, but the Wizard allows you to generate an XML File. This format should use UTF-8 by default.

Do you have the property listed here  (charset) ?

@OlivierJacot-Descombes  my problem is i have to use mapedit and filesaveas to save file as csv
bcos other side integration has all the validation based on data from this csv file
in mapEdit i pass "Task Export Map" these are speific set of columns which are required for integration. in case of xml these columns are different
and for xlsx all date format are mess, every user machine has different date format,
all format cannot be validated
Note: i export multiple CSVs from MS Project (task, resource etc) all this csv export i have used speciifc maps one of which is  "Task Export Map"

If the wizard does not work, then you might have to gather the project information to be exported "manually" and to use other .NET means to create the CSV file. E.g., the NuGet package CSVHelper.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes thnks will check it out
